# php/sql select all that expires within 48 hours

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a table with a field named `creationdate`, add 14 days to this value and you have the expiry date. (all in unix timestamps by the way, so 14 days would be creationtime + 1209600)

Now I need to construct a `SELECT` statement that will pick all rows from this table that are within 48 hours of this expiry date, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? You get all where now is between 12 days and 14 days of the creation date:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN (creationtime + 1036800) AND (creationtime + 1209600)
```

Comment: What a very elegant solution! Thank you so much, had not seen this approach before, so thank you for teaching me something new ;)